# How to Display No Results found in a messagebox in Vb.net?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, if-statement, datagridview

```
     MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=**********;database=librarydb;"
    Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim bSource As New BindingSource
    Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim Result As MySqlDataReader
    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        If ComboBox2.Text = "Author" Then
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "Select quantity as 'Qty',classification as 'Classification',author as 'Author',title as 'Title',call_number as 'Call Number',isbn_number as'ISBN Number' from librarydb.blist where author like'%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
            COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
            SDA.SelectCommand = COMMAND
            SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
            Result = COMMAND.ExecuteReader

            Dim search As Integer
            search = 0
            While Result.Read
                search = search + 1
            End While
            If search = 1 Then
                SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
                DataGridView1.DataSource = dbDataSet



            Else
                MsgBox("No Datafound")
                MysqlConn.Close()
            End If
        End If
```

What i want my program do is If the  user select the "author" in a combobox and write the name of the author in the textbox and it will display the results in the datagridview. Ive tried this code but does not work. It always fall to the else statement.

Comment: change if condition to `if search > 1` and check.

Comment: it falls to else statement sir.

Comment: put breakpoint at while loop and check if loop is executed...sometimes the datareader may have zero rows.

Comment: @G.Vister what are the item text in the comboBox? does it have "Author" (note the capital "A"). Or it has "author" (note the small letter "a")?

Comment: It works but it stock in the first If statement

Answer (score 2):

```
MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=**********;database=librarydb;"
Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim bSource As New BindingSource
Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim Result As MySqlDataReader
Try
    MysqlConn.Open()
    If ComboBox2.Text = "Author" Then
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "Select quantity as 'Qty',classification as 'Classification',author as 'Author',title as 'Title',call_number as 'Call Number',isbn_number as'ISBN Number' from librarydb.blist where author like'%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
        SDA.SelectCommand = COMMAND
        SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
        Result = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
            If Result.HasRows Then
                 SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
                 DataGridView1.DataSource = dbDataSet
            Else
                MsgBox("No Datafound") 
            End If
    End If
    MysqlConn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=**********;database=librarydb;"
Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim bSource As New BindingSource
```

> **Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable**

```
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim Result As MySqlDataReader
Try
    MysqlConn.Open()
    If ComboBox2.Text = "Author" Then
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "Select quantity as 'Qty',classification as 'Classification',author as 'Author',title as 'Title',call_number as 'Call Number',isbn_number as'ISBN Number' from librarydb.blist where author like'%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
        SDA.SelectCommand = COMMAND
        SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)

            If dbDataSet.Rows.count>0 Then
                 DataGridView1.DataSource = dbDataSet
            Else
                MsgBox("No Datafound") 
            End If
    End If
    MysqlConn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

Comment: dbDataset is not a member of System.Data.Set

Comment: Its Datatable Pl find updated ans and also always try to use datatable

Comment: What DataTablePI sir? i cannot find it